# LinkedIn API Login With Specific Account

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I would like to login using my own account in conjunction with the LinkedInApi. The problem I have is that most examples I can see either use a cookie or login interface for local users login credentials. However my aim is to login with my own specific account by providing my username and password.

I can then extract the testimonials from my profile and display them on my website.

Is this possible? And if so do you have any examples of how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this for a considerable amount of time I realised that the answer is quite simple.

If you make the API call on the server side you can specify the credentials. For example in an MVC application you might make the call on the controller action method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow users to login using LinkedIn you should first create an app in LinkedIn from the below link

https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps.

Then Add LinkedIn login button from this Url

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

Below is the link you will find the complete solution.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/145c93/sign-up-users-using-linkedin-and-save-users-detail/

I am not promoting the article, just providing the link where you will get the complete solution.